# Concatenate a tuple with a value that is on a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of tuples, and I want to concatenate them to values stored in a numpy array. Is it possible?

I've tried to use the zip function, because I want a resultant tuple like:

```
(original_tuple_value,numpy_array_value)
```

For clarification, a possible input is:
import numpy as np

```
tupla_data = [tuple(["String 1"]), tuple(["String 2"]), tuple(["String3"])]
array_data = np.array([0,1,2])
```

A print version would be:

Example of list of tuples:  [('String 1',), ('String 2',), ('String3',)]

Example of numpy array:  [0 1 2]

Desired final output tuples: [('String 1', 0), ('String 2', 1), ('String3', 2)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, like this -

```
In [69]: original_tuple_value = [('hello'),('all'),('long')]

In [70]: numpy_array_value = np.array([3,8,2])

In [71]: map(tuple,np.column_stack((original_tuple_value,numpy_array_value)))
Out[71]: [('hello', '3'), ('all', '8'), ('long', '2')]
```

Comment: I've got a message saying that the np.array is not iterable.

Comment: It was more like this: array([0,1,2])  and tuples [(hello),(all),(long)] to generate something like [(hello, 0) , (all, 1) , (long, 2)]

Comment: So, concatenating a list of tuples to values of a numpy array.

Comment: @RicardoBarrosLourenço `tuples [(hello),(all),(long)] ` doesn't make sense. Is it a tuple of strings or numeric values? Could you post minimal runnable sample input cases?

Comment: Yes, a tuple of strings. It is a data transformation for generating a training set for nltk naive bayes module.

Comment: @RicardoBarrosLourenço Please use the `edit` button to the bottom of the question and add a sample input case that people can copy and paste in their Python working environment and also post the expected output. Thanks!

Comment: @RicardoBarrosLourenço Thanks for the edits in the question. Check out the edits in the solution?